Cannot transfer SOL to some wallets
I am new in this ecosystem. I have a wallet A from which I can send sol to wallet B, D , E but cannot send C or F . If I am creating a new wallet in phantom I cannot send sol to that account as well. Keep in mind I have enough amount to make a transaction.
What is the problem here and how can I solve it?
